# how to make selected vertices rotate/scale/transform around themselves, not the cursor

Tags: modeling, camera, transform-orientation

this happens whenever I use the "cursor to selected" thing in a project and then the transformation point is linked with the cursor and it drives me nuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, it turns out it was just changing the pivot point